# Disable border or hover effect on selected images only

Tags: html, css

I have the following code to create a border around all images as well as hover effects, but how do I disable this on selected images (ie. social buttons or logo)

```
img {
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;
}
a:hover img {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
}
```

Comment: `img:not(whatever is special about them)`

Answer (score 1):

you could add a class to the image that you want/dont want to have the borders, then style them differently by using their class in the css instead.

Answer (score 0):

use the `css not selector`

like this

## html markup

```
<div>
<img src="http://images03.olx.in/ui/3/20/99/45761199_1.jpg" alt="not found"/>
    <img src="http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Facebook-Changes-Font-Size-Users-Grab-Their-Pitchforks-2.jpg" alt="not found" class="noborder"/>
</div>
```

## css

```
img:not(.noborder) {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

see the  [Documentation and use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)  here

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/FEvq8/)

Comment: @joejourneys check the demo fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should write in css the full path to the image,for example

```
 div.hover-img ul li p a:hover img {
     border: solid 1px #CCC;
     -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
         box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999; }
```

This additional class `.hover-img` and the path to the image helps you identify only the images you need to be bordered in hover position.

Answer (score 0):

add a seperate class

```
.noshadow{ border:none; box-shadow:none}
```

Add this class to the element where you don't required the box-shadow and border